# Select empty cells in R

Tags: r

How do I select empty cells from column D1 of my database (image attached)

I tried as follows:

```
df<-read_excel('C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/test.xlsx')
x<-subset(df,df$D1=="")
```

But it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it was read as `NA`, then use `is.na` to detect the NA elements

```
subset(df, is.na(D1))
```

---

Or if there are whitespaces, i.e. `" "`, use `trimws` to remove those and use `==`

```
subset(df, trimws(D1) == "")
```

---

Or if it is both (just to generalize), then do a `|` condition

```
subset(df, is.na(D1)|trimws(D1) == "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! From what I can see she's deleting the information that contains empty cells in D1, isn't it? In case, I wanted to select only those values that contain empty cells in D1.

Comment: @AntonioPedro You are right.  Can you try with the update.  I assume either this as `NA` elements or it is not completely blank, i.e. there are some whitespace like `" "`, in that case do `subset(df, nzchar(trimws(D1)))`

Answer (score 2):

We could use `complete_cases` from base R:

To select empty rows:

```
df
x <- subset(df, !complete.cases(df))
```

Output:

```
    D1 D2 D3 A1 A2 A3
2 <NA>  s  r  1  5  3
4 <NA> as  3  2  4  5
7 <NA> da  r  3  6  3
```

**OR**

To select non empty rows:

```
x <- subset(df, complete.cases(df))
```

Output:

```
  D1 D2 D3 A1 A2 A3
1  a  f  a  0  2  4
3  b da  d 12  3  5
5  c ad  f  4  6  7
6  d da  d  3  5  6
```